# What are the pros and cons of dealing with a very large dataset in qualitative research?

Tags: research-process, data, methodology

What are the pros and cons of dealing with a very large amount of qualitative data as a sole researcher?

Obviously, required time and resources come to mind, but what else?

Comment: What kind of research? Math, science, humanities, music...?

Comment: @Michael C. I'm personally concerned with social sciences but I couldn't find the question here so I think answering as generally as possibly could be worthwhile to more people

Comment: I think the biggest pro could be that you get the data all to yourself, so you can explore to your heart's desire. The biggest con could be inherent bias, which can be detrimental to statistical analysis.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data? Are you using qualitative methods or statistics?

Comment: @henning Qualitative methods (which is why I didn't post in cross validated)

Comment: @Emilie then it probably depends on the precise method. If you are going to code a huge text corpus, for example, the obvious downside is that it is going to take forever.

Answer (score 1):

There are no pros or cons just as there are no pros or cons to having $1,000,000 versus $1,000 to work with.  You are less constrained.  That is just a fact. The range of things you can do goes way up.  If you don't like things being larger, you can voluntarily choose for them to be smaller by sampling.  If you have a more specific question regarding methods, you should ask it on Cross Validated.

Answer (score -2):

If the proper big data processing is done, you have more data to use. The con is that 'big data' is still a relatively new thing, and the resources may not be available for you to use easily.

Comment: What is 'the proper big data processing'?

Comment: I'm not a data scientist. I've been doing reading on data mining, and this seemed like a good use of big data analytics.